# overflow-x:auto not working in safari and firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've checked several topics about this problem but none of them worked for me. I'm using Bootstrap. Here is my code.

**TEMPLATE :**

```
<div class="table-responsive for_safari">
    <table class="table" style="width:5000px;">
        <tr>
            {partners_info}                         
                <td>
                    <a href="{link_partner}">
                        <div style=" background-image: url('{img_partner}');" class="give_size">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </td>                       
            {/partners_info}                        
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.give_size {
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-size: 200px auto !important;
    background-position: center !important;
    height: 200px !important;
}

.for_safari {
    overflow-x: scroll; /* has to be scroll, not auto */
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Scroll doesn't work in Safari and Firefox and I can't figure out why. Everything works fine in Chrome. [Here is link where you can actually see the problem. Enter the page and scroll down.](http://pottersapp.com/IQ)  Hope you can help. Thanks.

Comment: it seems to be working here - firefox 38. Linux - (horizontal scroll). Did you fixed it?

Comment: Yeah i fixed it about minute ago thanks :)

Comment: i have tested it on my computer in safari and FF, all works ok !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was inside table class. "max-width:100%" was not necessary. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: So as not to mess with bootstrap, I added custom CSS ``.table-responsive table {
  max-width: none !important;
}``.  This fixed it.  Thanks!